# Using a constructor within another in Java

Tags: java, constructor

Consider:

```
    int a = 0;
    int b = 3;

    //Constructor 1
    public ClassName (int a) {
        this(a, b); //Error
        //new ClassName(a, b) //No error
    }

    //Constructor 2
    public ClassName (int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
```

**First question:**

I get an error saying "b should be static". Why can't I use the default value (3) for b in this way?

**Second question:**

In the first constructor, if I use the comment outed part, I do not get an error. Is it an acceptable usage?

Comment: You are constructing an object. You can't use the fields of an object you haven't yet constructed, hence the fact that b should static (you are using the b defined in the class). With b static, b would no longer be dependent on a specific instance. Secondly, using new ClassName(a,b) you would be creating a new instance of the same class in the constructor. It's legit, but it's not a substitute for this(a,b); It's a different thing.

Comment: I would be very leery of creating an extra `ClassName` object in a `ClassName` constructor.  See Paul Boddington's answer for details.

Comment: You're calling one function explicitly to call another. That just has no sense to it. Minimize your code, it helps things run fasteron any platform.

Comment: @brso05 I was referring to the bit in PB's answer where he says "People expect new to create one instance of a class, whereas using new ClassName in the constructor creates two.", regarding question 2.

Comment: @DavidPulse while this example isn't practical there are practical applications for this technique...

Comment: Yes there are! I actually thought," Well he just discovered overloading" so, that's a plus. But to explicitly, and only call the function fromnthe function, that part is worst case usage of the format. But yes, there are lessons in here.

Comment: See, @iwsnmw that is something people do when overloading. They use dfferent argument sets to setup how they want to construct their object. Or simply how to figure in a logical function. You would have different engagements to use different criteria, in order to suffice the needs of closely related, but dissimilar input.

Comment: You also learned a bit here about inheritance @iwsnmw. Anything named above, and in the class, is prospectively inheritable. It depends on the inheritability you give it. (Public, private, or protected) i', not clear on the latter, but the first is easy. Anything in the class that doesn't have a exactly typed dupe name, like you had here, is inherited to subclasses. And private can only have specifically those functions, at that level of scope, change the variables.

Answer (score 12):

The use of instance variables in an explicit constructor invocation is prohibited by [the JLS, Section 8.8.7.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1).

> An explicit constructor invocation statement in a constructor body may not refer to any instance variables or instance methods or inner classes declared in this class or any superclass, or use `this` or `super` in any expression; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
>
> This prohibition on using the current instance explains why an explicit constructor invocation statement is deemed to occur in a static context (§8.1.3).

You referenced the instance variable `b`.  The compiler didn't raise this error on `a` because it's a local variable, which shadows the instance variable `a`.

The "static context" may be why your IDE is suggesting to make `b` static, so it can be referenced.  It makes sense; the `ClassName` part of the object isn't constructed yet.  Replace that usage of `b` with something else, such as a `static` constant, or a literal `int` value.

To answer your other question, typing `new ClassName(a, b)` isn't an error because at this point, this instance has been constructed, and you're creating a separate, unrelated `ClassName` object.

Answer (score 6):

> **First question:** I get an error saying "b should be static". Why can't I use the default value (3) for b in this way?

The correct way to supply a default value for `b` to the other constructor is `this(a, 3);`. You cannot refer to instance variables until *after* `this(...)`. That's just one of the rules of the language.

> **Second question:** In the first constructor if I use the comment outed part I do not get an error. Is it an acceptable usage?

`new ClassName(a, b);` does something different. It creates a separate instance of the class. In my humble opinion it is probably not the best thing to do. People expect `new` to create one instance of a class, whereas using `new ClassName` in the constructor creates two.

Answer (score 0):

When using variables in classes, it is important to note where that validity of scope is. You've instantiated new a,b variants of the variables there. You're tricking yourself into believing those are the same variables. Actually they're in another address space. If you want to use your class variables you'll have to take out the parameters to the functions. Then they'll sync with the class you're in, rather than isolating the arguments a, b to within the scope of your function,